# What are reasonable decisions to make when performing logistic regression along with validation?

Tags: regression, logistic, p-value, validation

I'm not really a statistician but, in the words of Scarlet O'Hara in Gone with the Wind, "have always depended on the kindness of strangers.”

I have a data matrix corresponding to 20 trials with 15 predictors each. Ten trials correspond to "true" and the remaining to "false." I'd like to perform a logistic regression.

When I use all 15 predictors, Matlab gives me a warning that the data is linearly separable.

Q1: Is this an indication that perhaps I'm trying to overfit?

I then used PCA and experimented with reducing the dimension. Of course the p-values corresponding to the regression coefficients varied considerably.

Q2: How much weight should I place on these p-values?

Q3: I was hoping to perform some sort of cross-validation, perhaps "leave-one-out." Should I focus more on the validation and not worry as much about the p-values?

Q4: When using "leave-one-out," what sort of cutoff do I use to decide whether the data point retained for training purposes is correctly classified. For example, if have a "true" data point and the probability of it being true as estimated from my model is at least .5, is that sufficient to conclude correct classification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "linearly separable" error message indicates that your dependent variable can be perfectly predicted by one of the predictors - The observations are error-free, meaning that you would be able to know/determine the value of the DV simply by looking at one of the predictors.

Comment: Simply one predictor, or a subset of the 15?

Comment: Likely to be just one, but could also be a combination of several predictors - The key idea here is that the values of your DV can be perfectly predicted by the predictor(s), meaning that there is no room for a statistical model